# How to display double as DateTime format (HH:mm:ss)?

Tags: c#, winforms, datetime, double

is question about double and time format (HH:mm:ss) again.

I am trying to do a segmentation for time interval of every 5 minute before, starting from time now.

In order to do this, i perform the calculation like this:

```
private string Get_now(int minus)
{
   DateTime n = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes( 0 - minus);

   double now = ((n.Hour > 12) ? n.Hour - 12 : n.Hour) * 10000
                        + ((n.Minute > 60) ? n.Minute - 60 : n.Minute) * 100
                                + ((n.Second > 60) ? n.Second - 60 : n.Second);

   string string_now = Convert.ToString(now);

   return string_now;
}
```

The Calculation result will give me double number, for example, if the time now is 03:50:00, if i put Get_now(0), the "now" will be 35000; if i put Get_now(5), the "now" will be 345000.

This how I print the "now" to text box.

```
textBox1.Text = Get_now(0);
textBox2.Text = Get_now(5);
textBox3.Text = Get_now(10);
textBox4.Text = Get_now(15);
textBox5.Text = Get_now(20);
```

And here is my result at win form:

[image]

As you can see, all the Get_now result are display as double value.

What I want is to display in the time format as 00:00:00

This mean, the result must show like this:

```
42352 --> 04:23:52
41852 --> 04:18:52
41352 --> 04:08:52
40852 --> 04:08:52
40352 --> 04:03:52
```

Otherwise, if you have a better way to minus the time in every 5 minute (fix time interval) and display it as string format, feel free to drop your comment here.

Comment: Any particular reason regular [`DateTime.ToString("HH:mm:ss")`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx) does not work for you?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why you convert time to double? May be it will be simply?

```
    private static string Get_now(int minus)
    {
        return DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(-minus)
            .ToString("HH:mm:ss");
    }
```

Comment: +1 for solving a real problem. My answer is **too** narrow, even if still solves OPs problem.

Comment: Well... initially I was doing this because I want to change the data type from time format to double, end up, i decided to change my mind to display as string format.. As a result, I was turning on a big round about. TQ!!

Answer (score 2):

Use this statement to convert `double` to `string` inside your `Get_now` method

```
string string_now = now.ToString("0#:##:##", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

will return `09:21:24` for `Get_now(15)` call

`InvariantCulture` is optional, but it may protect you from culture specific environments

Comment: Thanks. I saw this statement in other similar post as well.. but I try "00:00:00" and it does not work... so I should actually change the 0 to #... Thank you very much